# Multiple represented filenames in NSWindow

Tags: xcode4, nswindow

`NSWindow`'s property `representedFilename` (and its friend, `representedURL`) allows associating a certain filename with a window. This allows filetype-specific icons to be displayed in the title, dragging the icon to create an alias, and right-clicking to display path to the file.

Associating a single file with a `NSWindow` is easy. However, Xcode4's window has not one, but two represented filenames, in both Snow Leopard and in Lion. How is this achieved?

[image: Xcode multiple represented filenames]

Comment: I really want to know this too. I think this needs Apple's internal API, but anyway good question.